# How to append multiple records to a table using Delphi XE 6?

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe6, firedac

I am using Delphi XE 6, FireDAC and MySQL 5.6

My FORM has a TABSHEET which stores many TDBEDIT fields of a customer record.

The CUSTOMER table is TFDTABLE.  Those TDBEDIT fields will use a data source related to that CUSTOMER table.

To append a new customer record, the logic is to:

1. call CUSTOMER table APPEND
2. Those TDBEDIT fields will be blank. User can input.
3. User can click the CANCEL button to cancel this adding
4. User can click the OK button to confirm adding new record.  Then,
   call CUSTOMER table POST

I want to have,  5 tabsheets so that a user can input at most 5 customer records.  Then, click the OK button will add those 5 record into the CUSTOMER table.

HOW can I achieve that ?

Using the existing logic, I have to use 5 TFDTABLE for the same remote physical MySQL customer table.

This seems not efficient, especially when the customer table is large.

Then, I have to use 5 data source for each TFDTABLE so that each of the 5 TDBEDIT sets of fields can use one data source.

Then, call the 5 TFDTABLE APPEND method to create 5 sets of blank TDBEDIT fields in each tabsheet... etc... etc...

This methods seems a little bit stupid, is there some other ways to do it ?

Comment: I think that you will need to have 2 cursors to edit 2 rows at one time (since those DB edits shows and allows to edit data only for the just selected row), so I think it is not possible to simultaneously edit 2 rows of a single dataset.

Comment: But if it's a real tab sheet UI and the user can see and edit only 1 record at one time, you can e.g. append a row and store a bookmark to this appended row. That way you'll remember the row and when the user switches between tabs, you'll go to that stored bookmark and edit the row. Post would remain common for all appended rows.

Comment: Thanks TLama.  I am also thinking of something similar.  Actually, my real biz application is more complicated.  I just use a simplified example for easy understanding the problem.  I will also use start transaction and rollback/commit.  Anyway, I will try it out tomorrow.  Many thanks.

Comment: Do you use a `TPageControl` or a `TTabControl`? Anyway build a form (PageControl) or a frame (TabControl) and a DataModul with the datasource you need. Every form/frame instance creates an own DataModul instance and works with that. Now you can have as much parallel inputs as you like.